# Eloquent filtering with multiple parameters

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I am writing a search functionality which basically looks up several tables.

The DB structure and relationships are as follows:

```
`users`
id
name
user_type_id

`user_type`
id
type

`user_nicknames`
id
user_id
nickname
```

User model has a `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo` relationship with `user_type`

and a `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany` relationship to `user_nicknames`

What I am trying to get is search against a specific searchTerm which can be found either in `users` table and in `user_nicknames`

This one is failing right now:

```
 $user = $this->user->newQuery();

 $user->whereHas('userType', function ($query) use ($filters) {
                $query->where('type', $filters['type']);

        });

$user->whereHas('userNickName', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
            $query->where('custom_title', 'like', '%'.$nickname.'%');
        });
```

Please take note that I'd prefer to use the eloquent relationships for this rather than multiple joins.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you checking against currenct (authorized) user?

Comment: No, @train_fox.

`api/search?s=Int&userType=loyal&api_token=TOKEN` this is a request example to help you a bit.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: @JonasStaudenmeir Yes, this issue is now resolved.

Comment: Did train_fox's answer resolve it?

Comment: Pointed me to a direction but did not really answer it, to be honest.
Many thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

In your User model add these functions:

```
public function scopeUserTypeFilter($query, $filters)
{
    return $query->whereHas('user_type', function ($query) use ($filters) {
            $query->where('type', $filters['type']);
    });
}
public function scopeNicknameFilter($query, $nickname)
{
    return $query->whereHas('user_nick_name', function ($query) use ($searchTerm) {
        $query->where('custom_title', 'like', '%'.$nickname.'%');
    });
}
```

Then you can use these on your controller:

```
public function search(Request $reqeust)
{
    $users = User::where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->when($request->filled('s'), function($query) use ($request) {
            return $query->nicknameFilter($request->s);
     });
    })->where(function ($query) use ($request) {
        return $query->when($request->filled('userType'), function($query) use ($request){
            return $query->userTypeFilter($request->userType);
    });
    })->get();
}
```

Comment: I don't see the benefit that they bring in terms of efficiency, to be honest.
Looks better for sure though

Comment: Oh, i didn't use your eloquent models. Let me fix it.